# How Reload WebView on react navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

How I can reload a webview to initial source when I click on button from navigator?
I can reset a original componet using?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
     const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {
  
});
```

Or I can reload the webview on component?

```
function TabOneNavigator({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {
      alert('Default behavior prevented');
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="Perfil"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'IzyJob' }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

my screen

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    url: 'https://www.google.com'
  };
  render() {
    return <WebView 
    source={{ uri: this.state.url }} 
    style={{ marginTop: 0 }} />;
  }
}
```

My idea is when page on webview is different of state.url and has a click on tab navigation I reload to initial url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First create reference for the `webview`, like given below

```
<WebView
    ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
    source={{ uri: this.state.url }} 
    style={{ marginTop: 0 }} />;
```

> Then call `this.webview.reload()` where you want, this code will help you to refresh your `webview`

Comment: how I can use this.webview.reload() in another component? i need use with ref?

Comment: create a ref in parent component and pass to webview component and give that ref to webview then you can refresh the webview by calling ref.reload() from parent